# jquery dialog box DIV overlapping

Tags: jquery

I created a jquery dialog box with an anchor tag. When I click the anchor tag, the content is shown in another div inside the dialog box. But the problem is, the font size of the message shown above the anchor tag get reduced.

```
function OnError(xhr, errorType, exception) {

    $('#dialog-showMsg #sp').empty()
    $("#ExDetails").remove();
    $("#dialog-showMsg").text = " ";

    $("#dialog-showMsg #sp").append("Error something bad happened", "<br/><br/>")
    $("#dialog-showMsg").dialog({

        draggable: true,
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        show: { effect: "Fold" },
        hide: { effect: "Fold" },
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            "<br />"
            $('<a />', {
                'class': 'DrilldownLink',
                text: 'Error Details',
                href: '#',
                id: 'ExDetails',
                style: "color:blue !important;"
            })
             .appendTo($(".ui-dialog-content"))
              .click(function () {
                  var responseText;
                  $("#dialog").empty("");
                  //$(event.target).dialog('close');
                  $("#dialog").slideToggle();
                  var responseText;
                  $("#dialog").html("");
                  //$("#dialog-showMsg").dialog({ height: 500, width: 500 });
                  try {
                      //$("#dialog-showMsg").append($("#dialog").append("hello moto"));
                      $("#dialog-showMsg").append($("#dialog").append("<b>" + errorType + " " + exception + "</b>"));
                      $("#dialog-showMsg").append($("#dialog").append("<u>Exception</u>:<br /><br />" + responseText.ExceptionType));
                      $("#dialog-showMsg").append($("#dialog").append("<u>StackTrace</u>:<br /><br />" + responseText.StackTrace));
                      $("#dialog-showMsg").append($("#dialog").append("<u>Message</u>:<br /><br />" + responseText.Message));
                  }
                  catch (e) {
                      responseText = xhr.responseText;
                      $("#dialog").html(responseText);
                  }

              })
              return false;
        },
        buttons: {
            'OK': function () { $(this).dialog('close'); }
        }
    });
}
```

Screenshots:

[image: before click]

[image: after click]

Answer (score 0):

The .NET error page has a bunch of embedded style tags which mess with your own styles.  The best thing to do would be to strip out the style tags from the returned content before inserting it into your dialog.

Something like this:

```
catch (e) {
      var $content = $(xhr.responseText).remove('style');
      $("#dialog").empty().append($content);
}
```

Note that I didn't test this, so you may need to tweak it.